# Live video streaming cloud service (architectural design)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure

I need to develop live video streaming.
I would like to do it using Windows Azure.
What architectural design can you advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Jeremy's comments: without knowing too much about your particular issues it is hard to say, but consider Azure Storage for Silverlight streaming... there are plenty of examples on the web that show how to do this:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/30/using-windows-azure-to-replace-silverlight-streaming-howto.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Without many many more details -- how much traffic? Where, geographically? How many streams? -- it's hard for a site like this to provide answers that are credible.

Given that you're planning on working with Azure you may find it best to engage directly with Microsoft. After all, they have a vested interest in making your solution work!